# Jquery opening a new tab getting no response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Alright so I am trying to open up a new tab from the jquery but I have few problems

1. The code doesn't call the window.open
2. I am trying to load the current path (localhost/bla/) and then open some file. But I havent found a way to do this yet, the only way I found is by using the static link (actually writing down the whole path manualy)

> ```
> case "success_password": {
>       alert("Welcome back. We hope that you will enjoy your stay!");
>       window.open('localhost/game/map.php', '_blank');
>       break;
> }
> ```

Is there a way to do this without writing down the whole path? So I could just use for example path + "map.php";

Comment: That still doesnt make my code work.

Comment: Try removing 'localhost' from the path, that will open the page `/game/map.php` relative to the domain you're currently on.

Comment: Aha thanks, I also just used window.location.replace("map.php"); and it seems that it did what It needed to do

Comment: Adding `http://` to the URL since you're defining the host potentially would have worked too. Or `//` for protocol relative?

Answer (score 0):

I just replaced 
`window.open('localhost/game/map.php', '_blank');` 
with `window.location.replace("map.php");` and it worked like a charm!